# Enforce an operation to run in an exact host in flink

Tags: stream, apache-flink

I need the source and output streams of my flink job to run inside the same node. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it in Flink (> 1.0.0).

Check this link [DataStream API - Task Chaining](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/datastream_api.html#task-chaining-and-resource-groups).
In particular you can use the `slotSharingGroup()` API.

This will enable co-location of operators which do exactly what you want.